# Abrir conexão mais de uma vez em C#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, conexão, connectionstring

Estou desenvolvendo um serviço em c#.

1. chama um função para verificar se tem registros ativos.
2. caso tenha algum registro chamo uma outra função para selecionar os dados referente a primeira consulta.

Quando executo meu serviço o mesmo dá erro de conexão já aberta.

Então antes de chamar cada função eu faço um `reader.Close();` e não abro mais a conexão nas outras funções. Porém não sei se isto esta correto e se seria a maneira correta.

Passo1

```
public int VerifyStatus30(List<Class.ReturnTableName> tableInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            var countDis = 0;

            using (MySqlConnection conn = DB.DatabaseConnection.getHSDBConnection())
            {
                conn.Open();
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DataObj, RecId FROM HS_REGISTRIES WHERE ErrorCode = 0 AND HandleStatus = 30 ORDER BY UpdateDate30 ASC LIMIT 1", conn);

                using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        countDis = 1;
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            int dataObj = reader.GetInt32(0);
                            int recId = reader.GetInt32(1);
                            reader.Close();

                            ClassTable.ReturnSapId returnSapId = new ClassTable.ReturnSapId();
                            returnSapId.GetSapId(recId, dataObj, tableInfo);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return countDis; // retorna a variável quantidade
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Passo2

```
public void GetSapId(int recId, int dataObj, List<Class.ReturnTableName> tableInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            Class.ReturnTableName result = tableInfo.Find(x => x.IdIntegraHardness == dataObj);

            using (MySqlConnection conn = DB.DatabaseConnection.getHSDBConnection())
            {
                //conn.Open();
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT AbsEntry,u_D005_id FROM HS501_ONCM WHERE RecId = @recId", conn);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName", result.TableIntegraHardness.Replace("'", ""));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recId", recId);

                using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            int idSAP = reader.GetInt32(0);//ID SAP
                            int idHardness = reader.GetInt32(1);//ID HARDNESS

                            Class.UpdateStatus updateStatus = new Class.UpdateStatus();
                            reader.Close();
                            updateStatus.Update40(recId, 1);
                            SaveIdSH(idSAP,idHardness, tableInfo, dataObj);
                            updateStatus.Update50(recId, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra que capturar uma exceção pra lançar ela de novo? Que vantagem acha que tem nisso? Só tem desvantagem! Pra que fechar algo que será fechado de forma mais robusta e correta no fim do `using`? E ao contrário do que foi dito na outra resposta não precisa usar `finally`. Se a conexão está aberta passe ela para o outro método em vez de abrir de novo. Vou escrever um código melhor, mas na verdade toda essa arquitetura já está ruim, mas não é o foco da pergunta resolver isto, e nem vale muito a pena porque quase todo mundo faz isso errado. Veja como o código fica mais limpo:

```
public int VerifyStatus30(List<Class.ReturnTableName> tableInfo) {
    var countDis = 0;
    using (var conn = MySqlConnection(Ambiente.ConnectionString)) { //isto estaria em uma classe estática que tem a string, mas pode por na mão
    conn.Open();
    var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DataObj, RecId FROM HS_REGISTRIES WHERE ErrorCode = 0 AND HandleStatus = 30 ORDER BY UpdateDate30 ASC LIMIT 1", conn);
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
        if (reader.HasRows) {
            countDis = 1;
            while (reader.Read()) {
                int dataObj = reader.GetInt32(0);
                int recId = reader.GetInt32(1);
                ClassTable.ReturnSapId returnSapId = new ClassTable.ReturnSapId();
                returnSapId.GetSapId(recId, dataObj, tableInfo, conn);
            }
        }
    }
    return countDis;
}

public void GetSapId(int recId, int dataObj, List<Class.ReturnTableName> tableInfo, MySqlConnection conn) {
    Class.ReturnTableName result = tableInfo.Find(x => x.IdIntegraHardness == dataObj);
    var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT AbsEntry,u_D005_id FROM HS501_ONCM WHERE RecId = @recId", conn);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName", result.TableIntegraHardness.Replace("'", ""));
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recId", recId);
    using (var  reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
        if (reader.HasRows) {
            while (reader.Read()) {
                int idSAP = reader.GetInt32(0);//ID SAP
                int idHardness = reader.GetInt32(1);//ID HARDNESS
                Class.UpdateStatus updateStatus = new Class.UpdateStatus();
                updateStatus.Update40(recId, 1);
                SaveIdSH(idSAP,idHardness, tableInfo, dataObj);
                updateStatus.Update50(recId, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DataBase/ConnectionParameter.cs).

Comment: obrigado pela resposta irei mudar para o que você sugeriu. Então seguindo a lógica que foi dada, eu precisaria apenas de um try{}catch{} no inicio de tudo que o mesmo se responsabiliza por capturar as exception e etc. Obrigado

Comment: Não é mais complexo que isto, eu sugeria aprender todos esses conceitos e ferramentas de código antes de usá-los. Aqui no site tem várias coisas sobre exceções. Você está tentando fazer algo complexo sem entender o básico, isso não dá certo e vai cometer um monte de erro e nem perceberá, porque boa parte permite funcionar, mas ainda estará errado. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%c3%a7%c3%a3o?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Comment: Entendi irei pesquisar e estudar o que falou.Grato.

Answer (score 0):

no fim de cada função, você pode finalizar a conexão com o banco de dados independente se der erro ou não, use o bloco finally{}:

```
public int VerifyStatus30(List<Class.ReturnTableName> tableInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            var countDis = 0;

            using (MySqlConnection conn = DB.DatabaseConnection.getHSDBConnection())
            {
                conn.Open();
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DataObj, RecId FROM HS_REGISTRIES WHERE ErrorCode = 0 AND HandleStatus = 30 ORDER BY UpdateDate30 ASC LIMIT 1", conn);

                using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        countDis = 1;
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            int dataObj = reader.GetInt32(0);
                            int recId = reader.GetInt32(1);
                            reader.Close();

                            ClassTable.ReturnSapId returnSapId = new ClassTable.ReturnSapId();
                            returnSapId.GetSapId(recId, dataObj, tableInfo);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return countDis; // retorna a variável quantidade
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
       finally
       {
          conn.Close();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Então o problema é que o finally é somente quando o código sair do USING. e note que quando eu entro no while eu chamo a função: **returnSapId.GetSapId(recId, dataObj, tableInfo);** e quando ele entra nela que da o erro de conexão aberta e reader ..

Comment: Entendi, então coloque o conn.Close(); logo após reader.Close();